# Using VSPE tcpclient/tcpserver in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I tried to create TcpClients and TcpServers in my C# program using VSPE COM service. Everything seemed okay except the TcpServer/TcpClient created took so much CPU time when running-- 2 of them can take 100% of my cpu time. Anyone can help?

Server creation:

```
string comName = "COM2";
string tcpPortNum = "5555";
string ipAddr = LocalServerIpAddress.ToString();
string initString = tcpPortNum + ";" + comName.Remove(0, 3) + ";19200,0,8,1,0,0;" + ipAddr + ";0;0";

// Create
int result = vspe.vspe_createDevice("TcpServer", initString);
```

Client Creation:

```
string comName = "COM3";
string tcpPortNum = "5555";
string ipAddr = remoteServerIpAddr.ToString();
string initString = ipAddr + ";" + tcpPortNum + ";" + comName.Remove(0, 3) + ";19200,0,8,1,0,0;0;30;;0;0";

// Create
int result = vspe.vspe_createDevice("TcpClient", initString);
```

Comment: The code does use the [com] service provided by VSPE, which is the Microsoft's Component Object Model(http://www.eterlogic.com/Products.VSPE.html)

Comment: I finally gave up using the VSPE to create com port- tcpserver & tcpclient. And completely programmed my own com-tcp server/client from scratch. And forward traffic from com port to tcpserver/client, similarly forward data from tcp to com port. However comments are welcome.